# Do multiple rolling sum using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-sum

I need to do a rolling sum of a columns of a dataframe, verify if the sum of the rolling (2 to 5 lines) is = 0 and take all the lines from the rolling to flag them as "canceled".

I tried this :

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values('No Piece FI')
df_sorted['No Piece FI'] = df_sorted['No Piece FI'].astype(str)
df = df_sorted[df_sorted['No Piece FI'].str.startswith('11')]
rolling_sum = df['CP'].rolling(window=5, min_periods=2).sum().shift(-4)
df.loc[(rolling_sum == 0), 'Annulé'] = 'Canceled'
```

But when I do that the result didn't seems to works. Also I would like to see the lines number like that or at least the group :

| Annulé | Lines | CP | Group (optionnal) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Not canceled |  | 8 |  |
| Not canceled |  | 4 |  |
| Canceled | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| Canceled | 2 | -10 | 1 |
| Not canceled |  | 3 |  |
| Canceled | 1 | 15 | 2 |
| Canceled | 2 | -5 | 2 |
| Canceled | 3 | -10 | 2 |
| Canceled | 1 | 8 | 3 |
| Canceled | 2 | -8 | 3 |
| Not canceled |  | 19 |  |
| Not canceled |  | 3 |  |
| Not canceled |  | 2 |  |
| Canceled | 1 | -8 | 4 |
| Canceled | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| Canceled | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| Canceled | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| Canceled | 5 | 3 | 4 |
| Not canceled |  | -1024 |  |

Here is what only the input would looks like :

| CP |
| --- |
| 8 |
| 4 |
| 10 |
| -10 |
| 15 |
| -5 |
| -10 |
| 8 |
| -8 |
| 19 |
| 3 |
| 2 |
| -8 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 3 |

How can I do that ? Thanks you.